# How are trading platform fees treated in capital gains taxes?

Tags: united-states, trading, capital-gains-tax, fees

How should I be thinking about platform trading fees when considering my taxable gains on short-term capital gains?

For example:

Bought at: $75
Sold at: $100
Trading fee: $10

Is my taxable income $25 or $15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cost Basis = (# of shares x share price) + commission

Sale Proceeds = (# of shares x share price) - commission

(note that the # of shares is the same in both of the above)

Gain or Loss =  Sale Proceeds - Cost Basis